# Divisor class group of $2$-dimensional surface isolated singularity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, divisors-algebraic-geometry, cohen-macaulay

For $n\ge 2$, consider the $2$-dimensional Noetherian local ring $A_n:=k[[x,y,z]]/(x^2+y^2+z^n)$ , where $k$ is an algebraically closed field of Characteristic zero. I can show that each $A_n$ is an integral domain and is locally regular on the punctured spectrum i.e. the singular locus consists only of the maximal ideal. Also, letting $i$ denote square root of $-1$, we see that $(x+iy, z)$ is a non-principal height one prime ideal in $A_n$, hence each $A_n$ is not a UFD.

My question is: How do we calculate the (Weil) divisor class groups $Cl(A_n)$ for each $n\ge 2$ ?

Comment: One can perform a change of coordinates and replace $A_n$ by $k[[x,y,z]]/(z^n-xy)$ whose class group is known to be $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @user26857: can you please let me know where can I find a computation of the divisor class group of $k[[x,y,z]]/(z^n - xy) $ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With @user26857 comment, this should have been clear.

Let $A=k[[x,y,z]]/(xy-z^n)$. You have a surjection $\operatorname{Cl}(A)\to \operatorname{Cl}(A_y)$. The latter is isomorphic to $k[[y,z]]_y$ and thus its class group is trivial. The kernel is generated by the height one primes containing $y$ and this is just $(y,z)$. So, the class group of $A$ is cyclic generated by the class of $P=(y,z)$. Since $(y)=P^{(n)}$, one sees that this element is $n$-torsion in the class group.

So to show that its order is precisely $n$, suffices to show that for any $d$ dividing $n$ with $d<n$, $P^{(d)}$ is not principal. But $P^{(d)}=(y,z^d)$ and can easily seen to be non-principal.